# Major and minor graticule for maps?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, geo, gridlines

I have created the following map, which has a uniform gray grid with 1° intervals both for meridians and parallels:

[image: Map with gray grid]

I would also like to have the meridians and parallels thicker and in black for every 5° interval (while keeping the 1° grid), so that gridlines match the latitude and longitude labels as shown below:

[image: Map with gray and black grids]

I know that MATLAB has [major and minor grids](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/graphics2-ex36962959-display-major-and-minor-grid-lines) for standard 2D plots, and I have used them in the past. However, as far as I know, maps don't have this feature.

I think that what I want to do can be achieved by accessing the map object properties (using [`gcm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/gcm.html) or [`getm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/getm.html)) and specifying a black color property to the specific subset of meridians and parallels (using [`setm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/setm.html)). Maybe the functions [`gridm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/gridm.html) or [`axesm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/axesm.html) can handle this, but I'm not sure.

In practice, I don't know how to do this as I haven't got any experience with maps. I would really appreciate a helping hand.

### Code:

> Note: This code requires the [Mapping Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping/index.html).

```
% Read vector features and attributes from shapefile.
landareas = shaperead('landareas.shp', 'UseGeoCoords', true);

% Define map axes and set map properties.
axesm ('lambert',...
    'MapLonLimit', [-70 10],...
    'MapLatLimit', [30 70],...
    'MapParallels', [38.00555556 71.01111111],...
    'Frame', 'on',...
    'FLineWidth', 1,...
    'Grid', 'on',...
    'GLineStyle', '-',...
    'GLineWidth', 0.1,...
    'GColor', [.7 .7 .7]);

% Display map latitude and longitude data.
geoshow(landareas, 'FaceColor', [1 1 .5], 'EdgeColor', [.3 .3 .3]);

% Toggle and control display of graticule lines.
gridm('MLineLocation', 1,...
    'MLabelLocation', 5,...
    'PLineLocation', 1,...
    'PLabelLocation', 5);

% Toggle and control display of meridian labels.
mlabel on;

% Toggle and control display of parallel labels.
plabel on;

axis off;
```

Comment: There does exist a [Geographic Information Systems](http://gis.stackexchange.com) StackExchange site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quite simple trick: Make a second `axes` in the same `'Position'` and make your desired major grids there.

Starting from your code with some modifications (I combined `axesm` and `gridm`):

```
landareas = shaperead('landareas.shp', 'UseGeoCoords', true);

% make the first axes and get the handle of it
ha = axes;

axesm ('lambert',...
    'MapLonLimit', [-70 10],...
    'MapLatLimit', [30 70],...
    'MapParallels', [38.00555556 71.01111111],...
    'Grid', 'on',...
    'GLineStyle', '-',...
    'GLineWidth', 0.1,...
    'GColor', [.7 .7 .7], ...
    'MLineLocation', 1,...
    'PLineLocation', 1);

geoshow(landareas, 'FaceColor', [1 1 .5], 'EdgeColor', [.3 .3 .3]);

axis off;
```

And then making the second axes:

```
% get the position of the first axes
L = get(ha, 'Position');

% make a new axes in the same position
axes('Position', L)

axesm ('lambert',...
    'MapLonLimit', [-70 10],...
    'MapLatLimit', [30 70],...
    'MapParallels', [38.00555556 71.01111111],...
    'Frame', 'on',...
    'FLineWidth', 2,...
    'Grid', 'on',...
    'GLineStyle', '-',...
    'GLineWidth', 2,...
    'GColor', [.2 .2 .2], ...
    'MLineLocation', 5,...
    'MLabelLocation', 5,...
    'PLineLocation', 5,...
    'PLabelLocation', 5);

mlabel on;
plabel on;
axis off;
```

You will get this result:

[image]

It is not even necessary to get and set the positions, since they both will be created in the default position.

Comment: Somebody might find this useful: If you wish to zoom both axes simultaneously use [`linkaxes`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html).

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

Use this slightly modified version of your code:

```
% Read vector features and attributes from shapefile.
landareas = shaperead('landareas.shp', 'UseGeoCoords', true);

% Define map axes and set map properties.
hAx = axesm ('lambert',...  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Change #1
    'MapLonLimit', [-70 10],...
    'MapLatLimit', [30 70],...
    'MapParallels', [38.00555556 71.01111111],...
    'Frame', 'on',...
    'FLineWidth', 1,...
    'Grid', 'on',...
    'GLineStyle', '-',...
    'GLineWidth', 0.1,...
    'GColor', [.7 .7 .7]);

% Display map latitude and longitude data.
geoshow(landareas, 'FaceColor', [1 1 .5], 'EdgeColor', [.3 .3 .3]);

% Toggle and control display of graticule lines.
hGrid = gridm(... <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Change #2
  'MLineLocation', 1,... 
  'PLineLocation', 1);

% Change #3:
hGridCopy = copyobj(hGrid,hAx); 
set(hGridCopy,'Tag','oldGrid');  % We use this to hide the grid from handlem,
gridm(...                          so that it doesn't get found and deleted.
  'MLineLocation', 5,...
  'MLabelLocation', 5,...
  'PLineLocation', 5,...
  'PLabelLocation', 5,...
  'GColor',[0,0,0],...
  'GLineWidth',3);

% Toggle and control display of meridian labels.
mlabel on;

% Toggle and control display of parallel labels.
plabel on;

axis off;
```

To understand where this hacky solution comes from, see the section below.

---

When look at the handle produced by `axesm`, we can learn something about the structure of map plot:

```
% Change from this:
axesm ('lambert',...
% To this:
hAx = axesm ('lambert',...
```

Then, `hAx.Children` gives us the following:

```
ans = 

  30×1 graphics array:

  Text     (PLabel)
  ... 
  Text     (MLabel)
  Line     (Parallel)
  Line     (Meridian)
  Group
  Patch    (Frame)
```

From this we learn that each collection of lines, i.e. `Meridian` and `Parallel`, is in fact a single object, which means all lines of a certain type have to have the exact same style - unlike "traditional" *minor* and *major* `grid` lines (which can differ). If we want *some* lines to be different, we must create a new object (subset of lines) with the desired properties.

Now, the easiest way to create these polar gridlines would be to call `gridm` again, but alas, this deletes all grids already plotted. How does it do it? `gridm` internally calls `handlem('grid')` which looks for graphical objects with a `Tag` of either `Parallel` or `Meridian`, the found objects are later deleted and replaced with objects having the new appearance. So what do we do? We "hide" the grid from `handlem` (see `Change #3`; by changing the `Tag` property of these objects), of course! Then we just create another grid and we're done.